How to Create TypeORM Entities for Users and Organizations with Roles?
A user can create as many organizations as they like. An organization can contain multiple users. A user can have only one role in an organization, but they can have another role in a different organization. An organization can have multiple users for one role. The user is the main table, so the JoinTable decorator should be in the user entity.
I tried by creating following entities.
This is User entity
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  ManyToMany,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToOne,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Role, Organizations } from '@models';

@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true, select: false })
  password: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  active: boolean;

  @ManyToOne(() => Role, (role) => role.user, { cascade: true })
  role: Role;

  @ManyToMany(() => Organizations, (orgnizations) => orgnizations.user, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'user_organization',
  })
  organization: Organizations[];
}

This is Organization entity
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, ManyToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '@models';

@Entity({ name: 'organizations' })
export class Organizations {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  type: string;

  @Column()
  size: number;

  @ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.organization)
  user: User[];
}

This is Role entity
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  ManyToMany,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '@models';

@Entity({ name: 'roles' })
export class Role {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.role)
  user: User[];
}

But by this entity user_organization table contains only user_id and organization_id. But I want this table contain role_id as well so that I can store user by their role in specific organization. What should I do? I'm new to typeORM please help.
